# how can I use special characters in the facebook wall post?

Tags: html, special-characters, character, facebook-wall

I'm using the Graph API to make a post in the users wall. My post is in spanish and I haven't been able to post characters like `á`, `é`, `¡`. I have tried using `htmlspecialcharacters()` and `htmlentities()` but they don't work. I get something like `�Hazte t� tambi�n miembro`.  Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

Try utf8 encoding your text string.

In PHP:

```
$encodedString = utf8_encode($theString);
```

JavaScript function found here:
http://farhadi.ir/downloads/utf8.js